# Laravel dompdf error "Image not found or type unknown"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, dompdf

I am getting error "Image not found or type unknown" after downloading PDF in Laravel 5.4 using dompdf package. Here is the method

```
public function pdf()
    {
        $users = User::get();
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf', compact('users'));

        return $pdf->download('Users.pdf');
    }
```

My view file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PDF</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            @foreach ($users as $user)
                <img src="public/storage/images/{{ $user->profile_pic }}" alt="" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I try with static image name (like following), it works

```
<img src="public/storage/images/image_1.jpg" alt="" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
```

But does not work with dynamic name.

Please suggest how can I can fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dompdf and img tag, image wont show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327915/dompdf-and-img-tag-image-wont-show)

Comment: Hi, its not the same issue as the one you mentioned. That post was about a fixed image which I can make work (see my post details). This was about dynamic image url. Secondly the solution there did not work for me. I tried it before posting here. In fact, I tried other solutions provided in stackoverflow and dompdf github page. Nothing worked  @milo526

Comment: Is this question about `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`? If yes, why not specify it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327915/dompdf-and-img-tag-image-wont-show/4328635#4328635) question you have to use the full *server path*
try:

```
<img src="{{ public_path("storage/images/".$user->profile_pic) }}" alt="" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
```

Assuming the image is stored in your *public* directory.

Answer (score 16):

in my case. it work on windows but don't work on ubuntu 20.

i change to

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ base64_encode(file_get_contents(public_path('/img/logo.png'))) }}">
```

and it work fine

Comment: this is worked for me . I used laravel 8

Comment: the only code that worked for me

Answer (score 11):

```
public function pdf()
{
    $users = User::get();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf', compact('users'));
    $pdf->getDomPDF()->setHttpContext(
        stream_context_create([
            'ssl' => [
                'allow_self_signed'=> TRUE,
                'verify_peer' => FALSE,
                'verify_peer_name' => FALSE,
            ]
        ])
    );

    return $pdf->download('Users.pdf');
}
```

Comment: This works for the remote images

Answer (score 9):

I've solved it:

1- Call the DomPDF library:

```
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/mi/LiquidacionesSueldo/include/dompdf/autoload.inc.php");
    ob_start();
```

2- Generate the HTML file, I do it with a function that returns a simply HTML table:

```
get_dias_goce_sueldo($_POST['run'],$_POST['dvr'],$_POST['cantidad_dias'],$_POST['desde'],$_POST['hasta'],$_POST['am_pm']);
```

3- Now, you must initialize the DomPDF object, note all the options that I set:

```
    $dompdf=new Dompdf\Dompdf();
    $dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
    $dompdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled', true);   
    $dompdf->loadHtml(ob_get_clean());
    $dompdf->set_paper('letter', 'portrait');
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("Solicitud_de_permiso_con_goce_de_sueldo.pdf", array('Attachment'=>1));
```

NOTE: in my function, in the HTML table, I call the image with the full path, this way:

```
<img src="'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mi/DiasAdministrativos/logo.png">
```

That's all, I hope this will be usefull, that was for me.

Comment: $dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
    $dompdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled', true);I just add this 2 option and images are loaded in my pdf. --- thank you

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `asset(image/location)` library to get your image, try replace with `public_path('image/location')`

Answer (score 2):

Adding the option is remote enabled to true works for me. After this image should be an HTTP URL.

```
$dompdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled', true);
```

The issue came when I moved my code from php5.6 to php7.3. Older code is still working on the php5.6 server where I was passing src as an absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

**Use This Way**

```
 <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ base64_encode(file_get_contents(public_path($Customer->customer_image))) }}" class="image img-thumbnail" height="100px" width="100px" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be OPTIONS issue. Try to setup these options:

```
$PDFOptions = ['enable_remote' => true, 'chroot' => public_path('storage/resource-booking')];

PDF::setOptions($PDFOptions)->loadView();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ base64_encode(file_get_contents(public_path($Customer->customer_image))) }}" class="image img-thumbnail" height="100px" width="100px" />
```

This worked but I also had to install the GD library.

```
sudo apt-get install php8.x-gd
```

Also, restart your apache service and Laravel server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your page **is not password protected**, for example when you are working on a staging environment.

The class needs public access to your page for this option to work:

```
$dompdf->set_option('isRemoteEnabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to set "chroot" to my working directory instead of default dompdf directory

```
$pdf = new Dompdf(['chroot' => __DIR__]);
```