# Can you give a help understanding how to properly solve "Image not found or type unkown."?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, dompdf

Im using laravel-tinymce-simple-imageupload so that is possible to have the tinymce plugin with image upload but Im getting an error "`Image not found or type unkown.`"

To solve this issue it seems that is necessary to change the url path of the uploaded images so that is used an absolute url parth. But, as a beginner, Im not understanding how to do this configuration.

It seems that by default there is a function uploadImage() in the `TinymceController` which implements a method for image uploading. (https://github.com/petehouston/laravel-tinymce-simple-imageupload#some-notes)

And it also says in that page that we can customize the uplaod url, so that when the uploading form is included with "`@include('mceImageUpload::upload_form);`" we can pass in the url of handling post image upload, something like `"@include('mceImageUpload::upload_form', ['upload_url' => 'YOUR_URL_FOR_HANDLING_IMAGE_UPLOAD'])`".

But Im not understanding what is necessary to create in the controller and what is necessary to put in "`YOUR_URL_FOR_HANDLING_IMAGE_UPLOAD`".
Can you give a help to understand how to properly achieve this?

---

To explain the code that I have. In the view there is a textarea for the user introduce some content:

```
<textarea rows="3" name="content"></textarea>
```

Is ncluded  the upload_form:

@include('mceImageUpload::upload_form')

And the jQuery for the Tinymce:

```
tinymce.init({
          selector:'textarea',
           plugins: 'image code link',
           relative_urls: false,
           file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
          // trigger file upload form
              if (type == 'image') $('#formUpload input').click();
                    }
   });
```

In the controller I have the code below to get the content of the text area

```
    // store in the column content the content introduced in the textarea
    $post->content = $request->content;
    $post->save();

    // then i want to download a pdf with the post content

    $pdf = app()->make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML($request->content);
    return $pdf->download('test.pdf');
```

The content with image stored in database has this format:

```
<p>test content<img src="/img/image_100.jpeg" width="1200" height="900" /></p>
```

But in the pdf the image dont appears and appears the ""Image not found or type unkown".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dompdf : image not found or type unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398779/dompdf-image-not-found-or-type-unknown)

Answer (score 0):

if `<p>test content<img src="/img/image_100.jpeg" width="1200" height="900" /></p>`

it's what appears, you should actually look your host file path  manually to know what's going on, besides that, your form has a path established to perform an action, so again, you should check your `Controller` and see what's going on, you are the one who has established the path where the image is saves, it's just a matter of looking where it has been stored manually and it will give you all the answers.

Comment: in what part of your code are u actually uploading the image?

Comment: Im using the package and it seems that is the package that have that part of the code. It seems that is this include "@include('mceImageUpload::upload_form')

" that allows to upload the image. And in the jQuery there is this part "if (type == 'image') $('#formUpload input').click();".